# What is the best way to handle a session-persistant search form in a Spring web application?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-webflow

I am looking for the best way to handle a session-persistant search form in a "shopping cart" like web application using the Spring MVC Framework.

I want to be able to navigate back to this search page, with last filters already set, from any other page in the application. This is not a master detail search results page, only a form with filters on a table of elements displayed underneath.

I can store my search filters in the user session, but what about multi-tabs navigation and browser back button handling ?

I also considered using Spring WebFlow to adress this.

Any suggestions ?

Comment: You should be able to do this via `@ModelAttribute` combined with `@SessionAttributes` or you can simply put the search parameters backing bean onto session scope.

Answer (score 0):

That sounds like a good job for the [*conversation scope*](http://static.springsource.org/spring-webflow/docs/current/spring-webflow-reference/htmlsingle/spring-webflow-reference.html#el-variable-conversationScope) of Spring WebFlow. Objects which are stored in this scope are saved until the current *flow* is terminated (or by timeout). The usual way to use it in your case would be to create a new flow/conversation when the user starts browsing the webpage and saves the search parameters in the conversation scope. When going back to the search page later, the parameters are retrieved from this scope (if there are available).

The conversation scope solves the multi-tabs problem and avoid to have to send back to the server every time the data (as you would have to do if you only use the request scope).

Comment: Nah... I don't like "application wide" conversations. AFAIK they don't and can't solve multiple tab problem. If user starts opening flow links in new tabs you will soon loose the flow state history and the original page with its state will become invalid.

Comment: Interesting. But using the session scope has more problems. What do you suggest?

Comment: What problems exactly? You mean like when searching from multiple tabs only the last search will be persisted? Isn't that the desired behavior?